# Not equal with null in inner join outputs different results

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

```
SELECT upper(unaccent(nome)), ouid, nome_dois, ouid_dois FROM clientes 
INNER JOIN dblink('dbname=XXXXX.org','select upper(unaccent(nome)), ouid 
FROM clientes') AS c(nome_dois varchar, ouid_dois varchar) 
ON nome = nome_dois;

 upper                           |                 ouid                 |            nome_dois            | ouid_dois 
---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------
 JOAO BAPTISTA                   | b9b1866a-3301-11e1-8cbb-82d9f077e206 | JOAO BAPTISTA                   | 
 OSVALDO DE ALMEIDA JOAO         | 1cd643ba-1bb5-11e2-a232-66341e648f0f | OSVALDO DE ALMEIDA JOAO         | 
 .........
```

---

```
SELECT upper(unaccent(nome)), ouid, nome_dois, ouid_dois FROM clientes 
INNER JOIN dblink('dbname=XXXXX.org','select upper(unaccent(nome)), ouid 
FROM clientes') AS c(nome_dois varchar, ouid_dois varchar) 
ON nome = nome_dois 
AND ouid::varchar != ouid_dois::varchar;

upper | ouid | nome_dois | ouid_dois 
-------+------+-----------+-----------
(0 rows)
```

My question is about `AND ouid::varchar != ouid_dois::varchar` The only difference between the  queries is this condition. But if the `ouid_dois` is null, why the `xxxxxx != null` is not working? The queries should output the same.

These conditions are both true, right?

```
ouid      ouid_dois
xxxxxx != null

ouid      ouid_dois
xxxxxx != yyyyy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL != NULL` returns false - you need to adjust your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT upper(unaccent(nome)), ouid, nome_dois, ouid_dois FROM clientes 
INNER JOIN dblink('dbname=XXXXX.org','select upper(unaccent(nome)), ouid 
FROM clientes') AS c(nome_dois varchar, ouid_dois varchar) 
ON nome = nome_dois 
AND (ouid::varchar IS NULL
  OR ouid_dois::varchar IS NULL)
  OR ouid::varchar != ouid_dois::varchar)
```

Comment: the first example works fine to me. the second will output 0 rows always

Comment: OK removed the second example.

Comment: You can use `ouid_dois::varchar IS DISTINCT FROM ouid::varchar` insted of current ouid comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong.  The first condition is *always* false.  Any comparison to NULL, other than `is NULL`, produces a `NULL` value -- which SQL interprets as FALSE.

So, the following are all false:

```
NULL = NULL
NULL <> NULL
x = NULL
x <> NULL
```

Comment: well, and there is any solution? I need the same output in the second query

Comment: @user2983258 . . . Use `coalesce()` or an explicit comparison to `NULL`.